# Pythagoras theorem quick calculation

Tags: algebra-precalculus, elementary-number-theory, square-numbers, sums-of-squares

How can I easily calculate this equation $x^2+y^2=76149513$ when $x$ and $y$ are whole numbers?

Comment: Are you asking for pairs of solutions $x$ and $y$?

Comment: Yes and also a shortcut way for his sort of caculations

Answer (score 3):

Wolfram alpha tells me 
$$76149513 = 3^2×11×353×2179 .$$

Since $11$ is a prime factor congruent to $3$ modulo $4$ that number can't be written as a sum of two squares.

(I could have tested for divisibility by $11$ by calculating the alternating sum of the digits.)

Comment: Can you plz explain in detail.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sum_of_two_squares_theorem

Comment: Note that divisibility by $11$ alone is not enough to show that the number is not a sum of two squares; you also need the odd power here.

Comment: @DirkLiebhold True. It's enough when $11$ occurs to an odd power - and easy to prove when the power is $1$.